# Unable to find "Macros" option while customizing Ribbon Visio 2016

Tags: vba, menu, ribbon, visio

I followed this document to create new ribbon and add Macro commands - https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c

I noticed that the "Choose Commands from" does not list option "Macros". Am I missing anything?
[image: ChooseCommandFrom]

I have enabled Macros in the trust Centre. Can anyone help?
TIA

UPDATE: Quick Access Toolbar also does not have option Macros

[image: QAT Choose Command From]

Answer (score -1):

You can assign macros to QAT buttons only. You need to choose the quick access toolbar instead if you want to assign a VBA macro.

The first step from the page says the following:

> Click `File` > `Options` > `Quick Access Toolbar.

Comment: I cant find macros option even in QAT. Added update in the question.

Comment: Did you try to restart the application? Are macros enabled in the host application?

Comment: Yes, I did.. still no luck

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/how-to-add-macros-to-quick-access-bar-in-visio/9cf84df7-1a66-46a5-a449-4e95caceedb0

Comment: I created add in, using designer ribbon in VS and used that instead.

Comment: In your post the `VBA` tag is used. Please choose correct tags to get right answers. Please upvote back.

Comment: I don't know if this might help at all but I suddenly had a similar issue where my macros had just disappeared from the dropdown and were unable to be selected. I later found it was because the "Require Variable Declaration" box had somehow been ticked (Maybe from a recent update), it is located in VBA > tools >options.
I unticked this box and they all became visible again!